# Login with FormRequest in login page doesn't give any effects (Redirected 302)

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get Indonesian Dictionary from KBBI for NLP research purposes, I noticed that it is a protected page, and need to do authentication login first, here is the snippets I use with Scrapy Python

```
import scrapy
import re
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy import Request

class scrape_kamus_kbbi(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kamus_kbbi"
    list_url = []
    ALP = [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)]
    sub_directory = "KBBI_FULL_HURUF"
    page_set = [142, 232, 47, 76, 38, 23, 75, 50, 43, 44, 
                239, 85, 343, 32, 26, 274, 1, 69, 195, 178,
                30, 11, 17, 2, 5, 7]
    login_url = "https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/Account/Login?ReturnUrl"
    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
    full_directory = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data Science Journey/Data Science with Python/Crawling Script/Indonesian Words/" + sub_directory + ".csv"
    for h in range(26):
        for g in range(1,(page_set[h]+1)): 
            text_url = "https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/Cari/Alphabet?masukan=" + str(ALP[h]) + "&masukanLengkap=" + str(ALP[h]) + "&page" + str(g)
            list_url.append(text_url)
    start_urls = [login_url]
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.words=[]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("Login page... Posting username & password")
        formdata = {'Username': self.username, 'Password': self.password}
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=formdata, 
                                         callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        for i in range(len(self.list_url)):
            yield Request(self.list_url[i], self.parse_page)
    
    def parse_page(self, response):
        self.log("Logged in... Grab All KBBI Words...")
        kata = response.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-3"]/a/text()').extract()
        for x in range(len(kata)):
            self.words.append(kata[x])
        kumpulan_kata = pd.DataFrame(self.words, columns=["Kata"])
        kumpulan_kata.to_csv(self.full_directory)

from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy runspider scapre_kbbi_kemdikbug.py".split())
```

but I still get redirected code 302

```
Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FCari%2FAlphabet%3Fmasukan%3DG%26masukanLengkap%3DG%26page29> from <GET https://kbbi.kemdikbud.go.id/Cari/Alphabet?masukan=G&masukanLengkap=G&page29>
```

I didnt know what goes wrong at this point. can anyone point a lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formdata you pass to the request is wrong.

Should look like this:

```
formdata = {
    'Posel': self.username,
    'KataSandi': self.password
}
```

[The correct request's params are these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPT4i.png)

But you instead send:

```
{
    "__RequestVerificationToken": "some_token",
    "Posel": "",
    "KataSandi": "",
    "IngatSaya": false,
    "Username": "{self.username}",
    "Password": "{self.password}"
}
```

Comment: I see, noted, so thats how to make a proper requests..  but I think the website url is highly protected, its shortly banned after a several requests.. :) thankyou anywayy

Comment: Here there are some useful tips how to avoid being banned: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned